# Create Validation Rules via JSS

Tags: jss, validation

I'm working on a Sitecore 9.2 JSS project that needs a required field that results to `FatalError`. The default required field in Sitecore is using `CriticalError`.

I can create it manually in Sitecore but I'd like to do it in JSS so it can be used in the creation of templates and in other future JSS projects.

Is it possible? Has anyone did this already and would like to share?

Comment: When you say create field with validation, you mean in code first approach?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you provide more details please. what do you mean by required field?, where and how you get those errors (FatalError, CriticalError)? can you show us how you create it manually and how you want it to be automate?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using the Code First Approach. In OOTB JSS, there are no attributes that allows you to specify the validation to use the Fatal Error. However, you can override the import process to have the field to use the fatal error.

**Extend your manifest data**

First, on the manifest definition, you need to add a new attribute. In my case, I named mine as `IsFatalField`.

```
export default manifest => {
  manifest.addComponent({
    name: "Welcome",
    fields: [
      { name: "title", type: manifest.fieldTypes.singleLineText, IsFatalField: "true" },
    ]
  });
};
```

**Create a new Sitecore Validation Rule Item**

As a best practice, instead of changing the current *Required* item available OOTB Sitecore, create a new validation at the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules`. In my case, I named mine as **Fatal**.

The validation is the same as the *Required* item except that in the Parameters field, I added `Result=FatalError`. See screenshot below

[image]

**Override the ProcessTemplates pipeline**

This processor is responsible to import the template to Sitecore based on your manifest. See below for code snippet.

```
public class ProcessTemplateWithValidation : ProcessTemplates
{
    protected override void ProcessField(TemplateItem template, Item multilistRoot, FieldDef fieldDef, ref int sortOrderIndex, IdManager idManager, AppConfiguration app)
    {
        ...
        //Remove code for brevity
        ...
        
        this.AssignRequiredValidation(field.InnerItem, fieldDef.Required, "Quick Action Bar");
        this.AssignRequiredValidation(field.InnerItem, fieldDef.Required, "Validate Button");
        this.AssignRequiredValidation(field.InnerItem, fieldDef.Required, "Validator Bar");
        this.AssignRequiredValidation(field.InnerItem, fieldDef.Required, "Workflow");
        
        //Customization to add Critical field validator
        var isFieldFatalString = fieldDef.AdditionalData?["IsFatalField"].ToString();

        if (!isFieldFatalString.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            var isFieldFatal = Convert.ToBoolean(isFieldFatalString);

            this.AssignCustomFieldValidation(field.InnerItem, isFieldFatal, "Quick Action Bar");
            this.AssignCustomFieldValidation(field.InnerItem, isFieldFatal, "Validate Button");
            this.AssignCustomFieldValidation(field.InnerItem, isFieldFatal, "Validator Bar");
            this.AssignCustomFieldValidation(field.InnerItem, isFieldFatal, "Workflow");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void AssignCustomFieldValidation(Item templateField, bool isFatal, string validationFieldName)
    {
        MultilistField field = templateField.Fields[validationFieldName];

        if (field == null)
        {
            Log.Warn("[JSS] - Could not find " + validationFieldName + " field on " + templateField.Paths.FullPath + "; validation settings may be incomplete.", (object)this);
        }
        else if (!isFatal)
        {
            field.Remove("{0E89EA60-AC6F-4619-8EDF-2057F307F19D}");
        }
        else
        {
            if (field.Contains("{0E89EA60-AC6F-4619-8EDF-2057F307F19D}"))
            {
                return;
            }

            field.Add("{0E89EA60-AC6F-4619-8EDF-2057F307F19D}");
        }
    }
}
```

In the overriden `ProcessField` method, the field definition `AdditionalData` property is read to retrieve the value of the `IsFatalField`. As the value is a string, it needs to be converted to a `boolean` and then passed to a new method (`AssignCustomFieldValidation`) I implemented.

Finally, you need a config file to patch the existing ProcessTemplates processor

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="ContentManagement or Standalone">
    <pipelines>
      <group groupName="javaScriptServices">
        <pipelines>
          <import>
            <processor 
              type="YourNamespace, YourAssemblyName"
              patch:instead="*[contains(@type, 'ProcessTemplates')]" />
          </import>
        </pipelines>
      </group>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Note**

- The full code is available at [ProcessTemplateWithValidation.cs](https://gist.github.com/hishaamn/8910e189319efd74d5e6697b71367de1).
- From Sitecore assembly reference, you can find it from the namespace `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Pipelines.Import.ProcessTemplates` in the assembly `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices`.
- There are room for improvement for this implementation. I just added a basic example how you can achieve the validation. You may create a custom method that allows you to add any other validation you have.

More information is available at [JSS - Extending the Import Pipeline](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/working-disconnected/extending-import).